# Can't connect to mysql using ssl with compiled php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, php, ssl

I have been bashing my head against a wall for a couple of days now. I just cant figure it out.

I Run ubuntu 12 with plesk 12 and apache 2.2.

I have tried compiled PHP 5.6.10 and PHP 5.6.11 with both variants of these options:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6.11-apache --with-config-file-path=/opt/php-5.6.11-apache/etc --disable-debug --enable-roxen-zts --enable-short-tags --enable-magic-quotes --enable-sigchild --enable-libgcc --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin --with-zlib --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-ctype --with-curl=/usr/bin --with-cdb --enable-inifile --enable-flatfile --enable-dba --with-xsl --enable-dom --enable-exif --enable-filter --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-gettext --with-gmp --enable-hash --with-iconv --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --with-ldap --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-mbregex-backtrack --with-mcrypt=/usr --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pgsql --with-unixODBC=/usr --with-sqlite --with-sqlite3=/usr --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-pgsql --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr --with-pdo-sqlite=/usr --enable-phar --enable-posix --enable-session --with-mm --enable-shmop --enable-soap --with-xmlrpc --enable-libxml --enable-sockets --with-pspell --with-enchant --enable-intl --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --with-tidy --enable-tokenizer --enable-wddx --enable-simplexml --enable-xml --enable-xmlreader --enable-xmlwriter --enable-zip --with-pear --with-pcre-regex --with-snmp --enable-json --enable-pcntl --enable-inline-optimization --enable-fileinfo --enable-zend-multibyte --enable-opcache --enable-cgi --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --disable-all
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6.10 --with-config-file-path=/opt/php-5.6.10/etc --disable-debug --enable-roxen-zts --enable-short-tags --enable-magic-quotes --enable-sigchild --enable-libgcc --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-openssl --with-zlib --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-ctype --with-curl --with-cdb --enable-inifile --enable-flatfile --enable-dba --with-xsl --enable-dom --enable-exif --enable-filter --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-gettext --with-gmp --enable-hash --with-iconv --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --with-ldap --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-mbregex-backtrack --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pgsql --with-unixODBC=/usr --with-sqlite --with-sqlite3 --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-pgsql --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr --with-pdo-sqlite --enable-phar --enable-posix --enable-session --with-mm --enable-shmop --enable-soap --with-xmlrpc --enable-libxml --enable-sockets --with-pspell --with-enchant --enable-intl --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --with-tidy --enable-tokenizer --enable-wddx --enable-simplexml --enable-xml --enable-xmlreader --enable-xmlwriter --enable-zip --with-pear --with-pcre-regex --with-snmp --enable-json --enable-pcntl --enable-inline-optimization --enable-fileinfo --enable-zend-multibyte --enable-opcache --enable-cgi --disable-all
```

I cant connect to MySQL SSL with PHP!

I get the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /xxxxx/test2.php on line 2  
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /xxxxx/test2.php on line 2  
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): [2002]  (trying to connect via unix:///var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) in /xxxxx/test2.php on line 2
```

My `test2.php` contains the following:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","axxxx5","Jxxxxxxxxse",false,MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL) 
        or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher';",$link);
print_r(mysql_fetch_row($res));
echo "Finished.";
?>
```

Note: I also cant connect with phpmyadmin to SSL which uses mysqli query instead of mysql_connect, so its Not a deprecated thing.

When I run a phpinfo, everything seems fine:

```
OpenSSL support enabled  
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012  
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

But when i check with the PHP module (ubuntu package) from console everything works:

```
$ php /xxx/test2.php
Array (
    [0] => Ssl_cipher
    [1] => AES256-SHA ) Finished
```

Comment: I'll have to look it up when I get a chance, but if I recall, the error referring to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` means the port isn't open on the server or the `mysqld.sock` file needs to be configured properly to handle the port you're trying to connect to the server with; even if it's on the same server.

Comment: There's no point to trying to use SSL over a UNIX socket.

Answer (score 2):

I thought that connecting to `localhost` defaults to using the Unix socket, rather than TCP. And then SSL might simply not be supported. At least for implementations using the original MySQL libraries: from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name **localhost** specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number.

Rather than using localhost use the proper host name or an ip-address to force a TCP connection. This requires both the MySQL server to be configured to support "remote" network connections and the correct ACL's to be GRANTed access.

Regardless, using TLS to connect to services on localhost is a complete waste of resources IMHO...